# Tomcat 8.5 + Java 17 + Eclipse = org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.lassFilejdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:406)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:231)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:207)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:174)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:201)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BlockScope.getBinding(BlockScope.java:500)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedNameReference.resolveType(QualifiedNameReference.java:999)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:636)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:684)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:1026)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolve(Block.java:117)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.DoStatement.resolve(DoStatement.java:226)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolve(Block.java:117)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.resolve(IfStatement.java:276)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolveUsing(Block.java:130)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TryStatement.resolve(TryStatement.java:1073)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolve(Block.java:117)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.DoStatement.resolve(DoStatement.java:226)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolve(Block.java:117)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.resolve(IfStatement.java:276)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolveUsing(Block.java:130)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TryStatement.resolve(TryStatement.java:1073)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolveUsing(Block.java:130)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TryStatement.resolve(TryStatement.java:1073)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:634)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:306)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:544)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1195)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1308)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:593)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/07 10:09:35 |       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:867)
```

after my server start up i am getting error in logs as well in UI part few button are not working
I am using tomcat 8.5.74, JRE 17.0.9

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65599

Comment: To the close voter "needs debugging details" ..?? The answer is right in the stack trace 8)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8.5 cannot compile JSPs with Java 17.  See [Bug 65599](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65599).

Either:

- Migrate to a later version of Tomcat
- Use an earlier version of Java

---

I would consider jumping to the [Jakarta EE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) 10 versions of these technologies, if not the Jakarta EE 11 versions arriving this summer.